# how to decrypt php code when encrypted or decoding of php files

Tags: php, encryption

as a new guy leaning web development. i was give a script by a friend to do some editing and in most of the php files i can not understand the lines.
all i get are lot of strings which i know is encrypted. was given the encryption information but do not know how to go about it. can any one please guild me through to to see the real php code so i can understand and do some editing. I was given the key.php and this is one of the file i want to decode.

Key.php

```
<?PHP 
    $host='localhost';
    $hostname=(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : exec("hostname");

    if($hostname != $host && $hostname != str_replace('www.','',$host))
    {
        echo 'Invalid Key File';
        exit;
    }

?>
```

and the instruction to decode is this

> To decode file Change in source code "eval" to "highlight_string" 
>   and then access the file through your Browser. You will see source code of the file there

And this is the php code i want to decode.

```
<?php if(!function_exists('f40132429')){function f40132429($fld){$fld1=dirname($fld);$fld=$fld1.'/scopbin';clearstatcache();if(!is_dir($fld))return f40132429($fld1);else return $fld;}}require_once(f40132429(__FILE__).'/94563597.php');$REXISTHECAT4FBI='FE50E574D754E76AC679F242F450F768FB5DCB77F34DE341 660C280D176E374DE7FB3B090A782B6B68DBC97BEAD93B681C452F25BE26';f40132429g0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498(f40132429f0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498(__FILE__));$REXISTHEDOG4FBI='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';$REXISTHECAT4FBI='94CD76CD371C5A7BC70C186E779C293B9B49BACA5A781A6'; eval(f40132429y0666f0acdeed38d4cd9084ade1739498('MTMzOTFFNjZBQ0FFRTkxNzIx',$REXISTHEDOG4FBI));?>
```

Please i really need your help

Comment: Sounds like ZenGuard.... goodluck with that

Comment: Unless you REALLY trust this friend of yours I would suggest you delete the files and go learn the language from the millions of unencrypted code samples on the internet. 99% of the time if the code is encrypted it is an exploit intended for harm. Never ever run eval on any code that you arn't 100% certain isn't malicious, better yet - don't use eval at all.

Comment: `$REXISTHECAT4FBI` and `$REXISTHEDOG4FBI` – hehe

Comment: @salathe haha nice catch